# What movie features a human-controlled robot wearing a clown outfit?

Tags: story-identification, robots, crime

I'm trying to remember a movie I saw as a kid.  Here's what I remember:

- A guy controls a robot by wearing a device. The robot mimics his movements exactly, so if the guy is walking down the street or fighting then the robot does the same.
- The robot is in a clown outfit for some reason.
- There is a scene where a girl in the shower is being attacked by some guy with a knife.  The plot is that they're trying to catch a bad dude by setting up this showering scene, but something goes wrong.  I can't remember if she gets stabbed.

That's all I've got.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[FX 2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101846/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)

That's not the actual plot of the movie but there is a scene like that.

> F/X man Rollie Tyler (Bryan Brown) is now a toy maker. Mike Brandon (Tom Mason), the ex-husband of Rolly's girlfriend Kim (Rachel Ticotin), is a cop. He asks Rollie to help catch a killer. The operation goes well until some unknown man kills both the killer and Mike. Mike's boss, Ray Silak (Philip Bosco) says it was the killer who killed Mike but Rollie knows it wasn't. Silak is involved with Mike's death, so he calls on Leo McCarthy (Brian Dennehy), the cop from the last movie, who is now a P.I., for help and they discover it's not just Silak they have to worry about.

### Clown Scene

Comment: That's the one!  Thanks!